# Delete document that has size greater than a specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a collection which contains a multiple documents whose size has increased from 16MBs or is about to reach 16MBs.
I want query that finds documents which have size greater than 10MBs and delete all of them.

I am using following to find the size of document.

```
Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne({type:"auto"}))
```

Is there a way to embed this query inside `db.test.deleteMany()` query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following query deletes the documents with size greater than the specified size (*the size is specified in bytes*). This query is valid with *MongoDB v4.4 or higher*.

```
db.collection.deleteMany( { 
    $expr: { $gt: [ { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" }, SIZE_LIMIT ] }, 
    type: "auto" 
} )
```

The following script runs for MongoDB v4.2 or earlier:

```
const SIZE_LIMIT = 75 // substitute your value here in bytes
let idsToDelete = [ ]
let crsr = db.collection.find()

while(crsr.hasNext()) {
    let doc= crsr.next()
    if (Object.bsonsize(doc) > SIZE_LIMIT) {
        idsToDelete.push(doc._id)
    }
}

db.collection.deleteMany( { _id: { $in: idsToDelete } } )
```

Comment: I used `db.size_test.deleteMany( { $expr: { $gt: [ { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" }, 105 ] } })`, and it worked. Thanks, but can you please explain why are you using `type: "auto" `?

Comment: I just added it from your query: `Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne({type:"auto"}))`. I thought it is a condition you are using (if it has no meaning for you, it is not required). As such, you can add any other conditions, if needed, as part of your query.

Comment: It turned out I needed the query for older version of mongoDB and the guy who answered it deleted his answer.
I copied the query earlier but have been running into problems, that query either deletes all documents or none, it seems if first doc matches, it deletes all the docs. Can you help??
`db.size_test.deleteMany( { $expr: { $gt: [ Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne()), 105 ] } })`

Comment: @sarosh I have added the code that will work with earlier versions of MongoDB (v4.2 or earlier). The code runs from the `mongo` shell.

Comment: @prasad_ where is the code you have added for earlier versions? I am unable to find

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
   { $match: { type: "auto" } },
   { $project: { bsonSize: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" } } },
   { $match: { bsonSize: { $gt: 16e6 } } },
]).forEach(function (doc) {
   db.test.deleteOne({ _id: doc._id });
})
```

Or if you prefer deleteMany:

```
var ids = db.test.aggregate([
   { $match: { type: "auto" } },
   { $project: { bsonSize: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" } } },
   { $match: { bsonSize: { $lt: 16e6 } } }
]).toArray().map(x => x._id);

db.test.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: ids } });
```